# As a junior programmer, how do I deal with conflicting instructions from two seniors?

Tags: teamwork, software-development

I am a junior programmer in the company. Two of my seniors have asked me to implement a function in two different ways. Should I write two different implementations as they have instructed, or ask them to decide how to implement the function?

Comment: Just write two functions

Comment: Take a look at SOLID design principles. ( Google SOLID software Design )  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about navigating the workplace and would be better suited to be on other stack sites like: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, why are you not using version control?

Comment: The core issue here is how a junior employee should deal with conflicting instructions from two seniors, so I have edited your question to apply to the more general scenario, and removed some of the situation-specific details. I hope this makes the question more on-topic, although it could be a duplicate.

Comment: Got to admit I'm slightly amused at the answers, a junior calling a meeting of two seniors ... I once had a dev from a company call a meeting of a managing director and financial controller of two other companies and waste our time.... I got him sacked.

Comment: @Kilisi You make a good point, but I assumed that the seniors are still his team members (possibly reporting to the same manager), not guys 6 levels above him. In the former case, it is completely reasonable to "request" for a meeting to discuss the issue, in the latter case, he should just inform his boss and do what the boss asks him to do.

Comment: This question is most definitely a duplicate of this one: [How can I deal with two supervisors with conflicting requirements?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2481/how-can-i-deal-with-two-supervisors-with-conflicting-requirements)

Comment: Since both senior developers are probably just trying to help you, and not aware of what the other said, just talk to one of them and it will be sorted. If you did the code twice they would both tell you off for wasting your time instead of talking to them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Call them both to a meeting, and ask them how to implement the function.** Let them discuss the merits and demerits of each implementation, and come to an agreement. Then do what was agreed upon. By the way, this is also a good learning opportunity for you. Listen actively to this discussion and ask questions when appropriate.

**If they do not come to an agreement, put the task on hold, and inform your manager.** Let him figure out how to push the task forward. Focus on the issues, not the disagreement, otherwise it would sound like an escalation. Rather than saying, "Boss, I am putting this task on hold because X and Y do not agree how to do it.", go for this:

> Boss, I discussed this task with X and Y. They have pointed out the following points that need to be clarified before I can do the implementation.

**You should *definitely* not implement two versions of the function.** You are writing code for your company, so writing code which won't be used is a waste of not only your time, but also the company's money.

Comment: If you cannot get them to a meeting, go straight to informing the manager. Making senior people sort out their disagreements is a manager responsibility, not a junior programmer responsibility.

Answer (score 5):

Software Engineering is not the scope of this site. However, considering the scope of this site, what you should do is grab both colleagues, get into one room and *talk to them*. Get a single working solution and then implement it.

That's normal workplace behavior. If you get conflicting information, get them to the same table, talk about it until you are clear on your objectives.

Comment: Replacing *write a function* with *cook a chicken* doesn't really change the point of the question.